# <!DOCTYPE html> affects css styles

Tags: html, css, frontend, doctype

I don't really know much about the use of `<!DOCTYPE html>`, that I forgot to include it in my current html file.

Then I decided I'd include it because I read that it's like the standard nowadays to include it so that you are telling the browser it's an HTML code.

However, when I tried to put it on my code, my main div's padding became broken.

**without `<!DOCTYPE html>`**

[image: Without DOCTYPE]

**with `<!DOCTYPE html>`**

[image: WITH DOCTYPE]

You can see on the second image, on the left side of the input boxes paddings are now off, compare to the first image with even paddings

Here is styling for the form input boxes and button.

```
form  input, #submit
{
width: 100%; height: 2em;
font-size: 16px;
line-height: 2em;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
border-radius: 3px;
padding: 0 10px;
}
```

And style for my main div (white container)

```
main {
position: absolute;
top: 50%; left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
background-color: white;
width: 400px;
padding: 16px;
box-shadow: 0 3px 5px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%),
0 5px 8px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 14%),
0 1px 14px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 12%);
}
```

I guess as best practice I have no choice but to include DOCTYPE tag, but if I have to do so how can I fix my problem with the padding? What am I missing or styling erroneously?

Comment: What you're looking for is `box-sizing: border-box` on the elements, where you want the `width` to include the padding. Otherwise horizontal paddings are added _on top_ of the width. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

Comment: Could you share which browser and version you are using? And I'm assuming that you're including `<!DOCTYPE html>` outside of the `<html>` tags? (It should be the first line)

Comment: So according to w3school here it is about <!DOCTYPE html>:-  The declaration is not an HTML tag. It is an "information" to the browser about what document type to expect.

Comment: Try to share the whole html and css files in both the cases